# Tictactoe checking tie game and checking the Spot that was already taken

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, loops

I'm working in this tictactoe program right now. Now, my problem is how could I check the **Draw game** and **Spot already taken** in tictactoe **without using methods**, only arrays. I'm stuck and I'm solving this for 3 days.

This is a 2 players Tictactoe.

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner wow = new Scanner(System.in);
    int players;
    int j=0, i=0;
    char[][] board;

    board=new char[3][3];
    board[0][0]='1';
    board[0][1]='2';
    board[0][2]='3';
    board[1][0]='4';
    board[1][1]='5';
    board[1][2]='6';
    board[2][0]='7';
    board[2][1]='8';
    board[2][2]='9';
    System.out.println("Tic-tac-toe game");

    System.out.println("_____________");
    System.out.println("|-"+board[0][0]+"-|-"+board[0][1]+"-|-"+board[0][2]+"-|");
    System.out.println("|-"+board[1][0]+"-|-"+board[1][1]+"-|-"+board[1][2]+"-|");
    System.out.println("|-"+board[2][0]+"-|-"+board[2][1]+"-|-"+board[2][2]+"-|");
    System.out.println("|---|---|---|");


    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {

        for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {

            players=wow.nextInt();
            if(board[i][j]%2==1)
            {


                if (players==1)
                {       
                    board[0][0]='X';
                }

                else if (players==2)
                {  
                    board[0][1]='X';
                }  
                else if (players==3)
                {  
                    board[0][2]='X';
                }  
                else if (players==4)
                {  
                    board[1][0]='X';


                }  
                else if (players==5)
                {  
                    board[1][1]='X';


                }  
                else if (players==6)
                {  
                    board[1][2]='X';

                }  
                else if (players==7)
                {  
                    board[2][0]='X';


                }  
                else if (players==8)
                {  
                    board[2][1]='X';


                }  
                else if (players==9)
                {  
                   board[2][2]='X';


                }
                else if(players>=10||players<=0)
                {
                   System.out.println("Invalid position");
                }
                System.out.println("_____________");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[0][0]+"-|-"+board[0][1]+"-|-"+board[0][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[1][0]+"-|-"+board[1][1]+"-|-"+board[1][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[2][0]+"-|-"+board[2][1]+"-|-"+board[2][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|---|---|---|");
                if(board[0][0]=='X'&&board[0][1]=='X'&&board[0][2]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");
                    break;

                }
                if(board[1][0]=='X'&&board[1][1]=='X'&&board[1][2]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[2][0]=='X'&&board[2][1]=='X'&&board[2][2]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[0][0]=='X'&&board[1][0]=='X'&&board[2][0]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[0][1]=='X'&&board[1][1]=='X'&&board[2][1]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[0][2]=='X'&&board[1][2]=='X'&&board[2][2]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[0][0]=='X'&&board[1][1]=='X'&&board[2][2]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                if(board[0][2]=='X'&&board[1][1]=='X'&&board[2][0]=='X')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }

            }
            else if(board[i][j]%2==0)
            {
                if (players==1)
                {

                    board[0][0]='O';

                }

                else if (players==2)
                {  
                    board[0][1]='O';
                }  
                else if (players==3)
                {  
                    board[0][2]='O';
                }  
                else if (players==4)
                {  
                    board[1][0]='O';


                }  
                else if (players==5)
                {  
                    board[1][1]='O';


                }  
                else if (players==6)
                {  
                    board[1][2]='O';

                }  
                else if (players==7)
                {  
                    board[2][0]='O';


                }  
                else if (players==8)
                {  
                    board[2][1]='O';


                }  
                else if (players==9)
                {  
                   board[2][2]='O';


                }
                else if(players>=10||players<=0)
                {
                   System.out.println("Invalid position");
                }
                System.out.println("_____________");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[0][0]+"-|-"+board[0][1]+"-|-"+board[0][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[1][0]+"-|-"+board[1][1]+"-|-"+board[1][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|-"+board[2][0]+"-|-"+board[2][1]+"-|-"+board[2][2]+"-|");
                System.out.println("|---|---|---|");

                if(board[0][0]=='O'&&board[0][1]=='O'&&board[0][2]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[1][0]=='O'&&board[1][1]=='O'&&board[1][2]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("X wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[2][0]=='O'&&board[2][1]=='O'&&board[2][2]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[0][0]=='O'&&board[1][0]=='O'&&board[2][0]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[0][1]=='O'&&board[1][1]=='O'&&board[2][1]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[0][2]=='O'&&board[1][2]=='X'&&board[2][2]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[0][0]=='O'&&board[1][1]=='O'&&board[2][2]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");

                    break;
                }
                else if(board[0][2]=='O'&&board[1][1]=='O'&&board[2][0]=='O')
                {

                    System.out.println("O wins");
                    break;
                }

            }



        }

    }   



}
```

Also, sometimes I can't break the loop.

Comment: What does you code currently do and what is the specific problem you can't fix?

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code. I don't really know what you want people to look at.

In reference to your question, to check for a spot already taken:

```
if(board[x][y] == 'X' || board[x][y] == 'O') {
//choose another spot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the user where to place the next piece you need to check your board variable if the current spot already contains and X or an O. This can be done with a simple if-statement

```
if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][0] == 'O') { // you need to check the whole board, not just [0][0], but you get the point.
```

If it does, ask the user to enter a new, legal, move. This can be accomplished with a simple [Do-While Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

I would also suggest you look into the [Switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), which will make your code a lot easier to read. For exampled the first part of your code, line 34-73 could be replaced with the following:

```
switch (players) {
case 1: board[0][0]='X'; break;
case 2: board[0][3]='X'; break;
case 3: board[0][2]='X'; break;
case 4: board[1][0]='X'; break;
case 5: board[1][4]='X'; break;
case 6: board[1][2]='X'; break;
case 7: board[2][0]='X'; break;
case 8: board[2][5]='X'; break;
case 9: board[2][2]='X'; break;
default: System.out.println("Invalid position");
}
```

.

**Edit:** Related to how to determine a tie.

Do you understand how a game can tie in Tic-Tac-Toe? Once you know that determining a tie shouldn't be too difficult.

Hint: If your code reaches a point where the board is full and no winner is declared, the game must have tied. (after for-loops)

Comment: Sorry, we're not allowed to use Switch Statements, how about the draw or a tie game? Any suggestions?

Comment: I added some more information on how you can determine if a tie has happened